# How to make a cumulative sum in blocks with results according to until the day before instead of each line?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, cumsum

Example of my CSV:

```
clock_now,competition,market_name,back,lay
2022/08/09,South African Premier Division,Over/Under 0.5 Goals,0.28985,-1.0
2022/08/12,South African Premier Division,Over/Under 0.5 Goals,-1.0,1.28
2022/09/07,South African Premier Division,Over/Under 0.5 Goals,0.37,-1.0
2022/09/07,South African Premier Division,Over/Under 0.5 Goals,0.20,-1.0
2022/10/15,South African Premier Division,Over/Under 0.5 Goals,0.20,1.0
2022/10/15,South African Premier Division,Over/Under 0.5 Goals,0.20,1.0
2022/10/15,South African Premier Division,Over/Under 0.5 Goals,0.20,1.0
2022/11/20,South African Premier Division,Over/Under 0.5 Goals,0.20,1.0
```

The results that are recorded in the `back` column and the `lay` column are updated every midnight (`00:00`).

So when I try to analyze the cumulative sum to know which rows are above zero throughout the day (the `combinations` list of lists is like a looping because there are several types of columns combinations that I analyze, I just summarized to facilitate the example in the question):

```python
combinations = [['market_name', 'competition']]
for cbnt in combinations:
    df['invest'] = df.groupby(cbnt)['lay'].cumsum().gt(df['lay'])
```

The current result is this:

```
    clock_now  cumulativesum  invest
0  2022/08/09          -1.00   False
1  2022/08/12           0.28   False
2  2022/09/07          -0.72    True
3  2022/09/07          -1.72   False
4  2022/10/15          -0.72   False
5  2022/10/15           0.28   False
6  2022/10/15           1.28    True
7  2022/11/20           2.28    True
```

But the expected result is this:

Until `2022/08/09` the sum was `0` then `False`
Until `2022/08/12` the sum was `-1` then `False`
Until `2022/09/07` the sum was `+0.28` then `True`
Until `2022/09/07` the sum was `+0.28` then `True`
Until `2022/10/15` the sum was `-1.72` then `False`
Until `2022/10/15` the sum was `-1.72` then `False`
Until `2022/10/15` the sum was `-1.72` then `False`
Until `2022/11/20` the sum was `+1.28` so `True`

How should I proceed to be able to add this cumulative sum according to the dates?

Comment: I'm confused... the clock_now column isn't being used in your code

Comment: Yes, this question is confusing, can you show why you expected True True with the actual numbers from this example data?

Comment: Hello @Chrysophylaxs , sorry for the failure to create the question, in fact I wanted to demonstrate what the current result is and then how I would like it to be, because I could not find a way to reach the result that I expected, I could not find a way to create this cumulative sum according to the date to deliver daily results according to past days instead of accumulating line by line.

Comment: Hello @ScottBoston , the comment made was also for you to see, I'm sorry for the failure in the initial explanation of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `shift` your `cumsum` per group:

```
combinations = [['market_name', 'competition']]
for cbnt in combinations:
    df['invest'] = (df.groupby(cbnt)['lay']
                      .apply(lambda s: s.cumsum().shift(fill_value=0))
                      .gt(df['lay'])
                   )
    print(df['invest'])
```

*NB. the first value is `True` as `0 > -1`, if you want `False`, remove the `fill_value=0`.*

Output:

```
0     True
1    False
2     True
3     True
4    False
5    False
6    False
7     True
Name: invest, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Hi @mozway, using this example: ```clock_now,competition,market_name,back,lay
2022/08/09,South African Premier Division,Over/Under 0.5 Goals,0.28985,-1.0
2022/08/12,South African Premier Division,Over/Under 0.5 Goals,-1.0,1.28
2022/09/07,South African Premier Division,Over/Under 0.5 Goals,0.20,-1.0
2022/10/15,South African Premier Division,Over/Under 0.5 Goals,0.20,1.0
2022/10/15,South African Premier Division,Over/Under 0.5 Goals,0.20,-1.0
2022/11/20,South African Premier Division,Over/Under 0.5 Goals,0.20,1.0
```

Comment: For some reason it is delivering one ```False``` and one ```True``` on the date ```2022/10/15```, when it should always deliver the same result for each day, could you help me understand why this is happening?

Comment: I also noticed that if you keep only one line in the date ```2022/10/15```, that being the one whose lay value is ```1```, even if the result is positive in ```+0.28``` in the cumulative sum, it delivers as ```False``` instead of ```True```.

Comment: but the `lay` is different for those two rows, no?

Comment: Yes, but as it is the same day, in theory it should maintain a pattern for each day because the results are only recorded at midnight, there would be no way for him to verify that on the day he had a positive and a negative. Because the default would be to deliver the same True or False for everyone that is the same day.

Comment: I decided to separate the cases, here is the detailed question on the maintain default issue for each day → https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75009431/using-shift-in-cumsum-to-maintain-a-default- of-true-false-for-each-date