# Maintain a default of True/False for each date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, cumsum

During the day, new investment possibilities are registered, but the results (`lay` column) are only registered at midnight each day.

So let's assume this `CSV`:

```
clock_now,competition,market_name,lay
2022/12/30,A,B,-1
2022/12/31,A,B,1.28
2023/01/01,A,B,-1
2023/01/02,A,B,1
2023/01/03,A,B,1
2023/01/04,A,B,
2023/01/04,A,B,
2023/01/04,A,B,
```

Until yesterday, `2023/01/03`, the sum of the lines that have the value `A` in `competition` and `B` in `market_name`, was `+1.28`

I only invest if it is above `0`, so during today, every time this combination of values comes, the answer will be `True` to invest.

At the end of the day, when the lay values are registered, I look at the total result:

```
clock_now,competition,market_name,lay
2022/12/30,A,B,-1
2022/12/31,A,B,1.28
2023/01/01,A,B,-1
2023/01/02,A,B,1
2023/01/03,A,B,1
2023/01/04,A,B,-1
2023/01/04,A,B,-1
2023/01/04,A,B,-1
```

End of the day: `-1,72`

This means that tomorrow, if that same combination of values appears in the columns, I will not invest once because it will always be negative because it only calculates the values that it has until the previous day.

I'm trying to create a column to show where it was True and where it was False:

```python
df = pd.read_csv('example.csv')
combinations = [['market_name', 'competition']]
for cbnt in combinations:
    df['invest'] = (df.groupby(cbnt)['lay']
                      .apply(lambda s: s.cumsum().shift())
                      .gt(df['lay'])
                   )

    df['cumulative'] = (df.groupby(cbnt)['lay']
                      .apply(lambda s: s.cumsum().shift())
                   )

    print(df[['clock_now','invest','cumulative']])
```

But the result is this:

```
    clock_now  invest  cumulative
0  2022/12/30   False         NaN
1  2022/12/31   False       -1.00
2  2023/01/01    True        0.28
3  2023/01/02   False       -0.72
4  2023/01/03   False        0.28
5  2023/01/04    True        1.28
6  2023/01/04    True        0.28
7  2023/01/04    True       -0.72
```

The expected result would be this:

```
    clock_now  invest  cumulative
0  2022/12/30   False         NaN
1  2022/12/31   False       -1.00
2  2023/01/01    True        0.28
3  2023/01/02   False       -0.72
4  2023/01/03    True        0.28
5  2023/01/04    True        1.28
6  2023/01/04    True        0.28
7  2023/01/04    True       -1.72
```

How should I proceed so that `cumsum` can understand that attention must be paid to maintaining a daily pattern according to the results of previous days?

Example Two:

```
clock_now,competition,market_name,lay
2022/08/09,A,B,-1.0
2022/08/12,A,B,1.28
2022/09/07,A,B,-1.0
2022/10/15,A,B,1.0
2022/10/15,A,B,-1.0
2022/11/20,A,B,1.0
```

Note that on `2022/10/15`, it is delivering one `False` and one `True`, so in fact it is not tracking according to the date which is how I want it to happen:

```
    clock_now  invest  cumulative
0  2022/08/09   False         NaN
1  2022/08/12   False       -1.00
2  2022/09/07    True        0.28
3  2022/10/15   False       -0.72
4  2022/10/15    True        0.28
5  2022/11/20   False       -0.72
```

The correct would be always or all `False` or all `True` when on equal dates. Like this:

```
    clock_now  invest  cumulative
0  2022/08/09   False         NaN
1  2022/08/12   False       -1.00
2  2022/09/07    True        0.28
3  2022/10/15   False       -0.72
4  2022/10/15   False        0.28
5  2022/11/20   False       -0.72
```

Comment: With pandas `1.5.2` and running exactly this code and example .csv, I get neither of your results. Four first `invest` values are the same, but rows 4,5,6,7 are (False, True, True, *True*) and cumulative is (0.28, 1.28, 0.28, **-0.72**). Can you specify which python and pandas versions you're using?

Comment: Hello @evilmandarine , I updated the question as there was indeed a wrong value in the print (don't know why → but in any case, it is not generating the result I expected, which would be to follow exactly by the date, always limiting it to the date of the previous day.), now it's exactly like what I get using Pandas version 1.4.2 and Python 3.10.4

Comment: And @evilmandarine I added one more example of tests in the question.

Comment: Still not sure I quite understand the goal. You cannot group by date and at the same time not group by date. It's not clear if true/false relates to each *row* or each *date*. What should the result look like with [this data](https://pastebin.com/a3hVXSFt)?

Comment: @evilmandarine using this data all from date ```2022/12/30``` would be ```False``` (because there are no values in previous days, so zero or less than zero ```False```) and all from date ```2022/12/31``` would be ```True``` because the total sum of investments up to the previous day was ```+3```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```python
(df.join(
    # Count market&competition specific cumsum for each row
    # and join back with df
    df.groupby(['market_name', 'competition']).lay.cumsum().rename('lay_cumsum') > 0
)
# Group by market&comp&date to get last cumsum within each day
.groupby(['market_name', 'competition', 'clock_now']) 
# Get cumsum Series for each group
.lay_cumsum
# Getting last cumsum within group
.last()
# Group by market&comp
.groupby(['market_name', 'competition'])
# Shift by one to assign to each date prev date's cumsum
.shift(1)
.rename('lay_cumsum')
.reset_index()
# Merge back with original df
.merge(df, on=['clock_now', 'market_name', 'competition']))
```

This will output

```
  market_name competition   clock_now lay_cumsum   lay
0           B           A  2022/12/30        NaN -1.00
1           B           A  2022/12/31      False  1.28
2           B           A  2023/01/01       True -1.00
3           B           A  2023/01/02      False  1.00
4           B           A  2023/01/03       True  1.00
5           B           A  2023/01/04       True -1.00
6           B           A  2023/01/04       True -1.00
7           B           A  2023/01/04       True -1.00
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for support! Could you help me understand how I could achieve the same result, but when I use column combinations for groupby? For example, ```['market_name', 'competition']``` (I analyze several different combinations of columns, so I even put the ```for cbnt in combinations:``` in the question)

Comment: Oh, sorry, I completely forgot about that requirement. Updated my answer, sorry, it's a bit ugly :)